# Set sprite for UI2DSprite from NGUI at runtime

Tags: unity, sprites, resource-management, ngui

How can I set sprite for UI2DSprite from NGUI at runtime?

This is what I tried:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<UI2DSprite>().sprite2D = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Assets/Content/UI/level/notLife.png");
```

I tried not to write `.png` in the end but it did not help as well.

Here is my Project view so that to prove you that I am using the right path:

[image]

And the problem here is that instead of showing me the newly placed sprite my old one disappears and nothing else happens.

So, how can I change sprite in UI2DSprite in NGUI from script?